# Redis Multiple Instance in FreeBSD

Tags: redis, instance, freebsd

im trying to learn FreeBSD, and i like to install multiple instance of Redis on it. i know this is easy in linux by just running the ./install_server script.

i've tried running the script from utils but as expected it wont work in bsd. as it installs in /etc/init.d

is there anyone who could direct me where to learn doing multiple instance of redis under freeBSD or teach me how to do it?

im new in freeBSD, and i want to learn it. i came from linux and OS X.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The default install on FreeBSD only runs one instance, as usual for daemons.

But you can run multiple instances by hand. Of course you'd have to 
write a different configuration file for each instance, using a separate port, and maybe a different directory where to dump databases.

Why not use multiple databases in one redis instance?